# Compile PHP 5.4.10 with JPEG for GD

Tags: php, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to make this for for hours now.
PHP won't compile against libjpeg.

This is what .configure says:

```
checking for the location of libvpx... no
checking for the location of libjpeg... /usr
checking for the location of libpng... yes
checking for the location of libXpm... no
```

So no yes, no no.

jpeglib.h is located in /usr/include/jpeglib.h
libjpeg.so is located in /usr/lib/libjpeg.so

I read through the .configure script bout could't find a quick solution.
I'm running Ubuntu 8.04

Any hints on this?

EDIT: The same seems to happen with the freetype libraries.

Comment: Try adding `--with-libdir=/usr/lib/` ?

Comment: Maybe updating the OS is an option?

Comment: @CyrilN. this breaks the Openssl library path

Comment: @KingCrunch unfortunately i will have to stick with 8.04 a while longer

Answer (score 0):

add `--with-gd` `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/` `--with-png-dir=/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

On a CentOS 5 system (with both `jpeglib.h` and `libjpeg.so` also located in `/usr/include/jpeglib.h` and `/usr/lib/libjpeg.so`, respectively), I had to include the following options when running the `configure` script:

`--with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr`

This provides GD support for both JPEG and Freetype (I didn’t have to do anything special for GD to support PNG or GIF).

Note: if you’ve already compiled PHP before noticing that GD doesn’t include support for these libraries, you have to run `make clean` after re-running the `configure` script.